# Unable to capture the whole URL string with Bottle web framework

Tags: python-3.x, bottle

I have a small Bottle hello world type code :

```
from bottle import route, run, template

@route('/<name>')
def index(name):
    return template('<b>Hello {{name}}</b>!', name=name)

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

Now when i type the below string in the browser(chrome):

```
http://localhost:8080/navigator?search_term=arrow/
```

it comes up with the message :
Hello navigator!

My objective is to capture the term arrow inside the name argument so that i can use that to display something else using the index function .

Please help me as to how to capture the term arrow in the URL that i supplied.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've confused the url's `path` and its `query args`. Here's how to get your query arg:

```
from bottle import route, run, template, request

@route('/navigator')
def index():
    name = request.params['search_term']
    return template('<b>Hello {{name}}</b>!', name=name)

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

This produces the result you want:

```
% curl 'http://localhost:8080/navigator?search_term=arrow/'
<b>Hello arrow/</b>!
```

Documentation is [here](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.BaseRequest.params). Good luck!